# Return an @include from Controller DataTables Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I am trying to re-write an table from my view to a DataTables for easy filtering etc. For this I am using [yajra/laravel-datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables). Within my original view I would conditionally return the following line:

```
 @include("partials.delete", ["id" => $advice->id, "url" => URL::action("AdviceController@destroy")])
```

I would now need to return this line from my Controller which uses DataTables. But unfortuanlly, I can't seem to get it right. I also haven't found other people with this issue. My code in the controller is defined like:

```
    return Datatables::of($advice)
        ->addColumn('delete', function($row){
            if($row->original_user_id == \Auth::id()){
                return '{{ @include("partials.delete", ["id" => '.$advice->id.', "url" => URL::action("AdviceController@destroy")]) }}';
            }
        })
        ->make(true);
```

But this literally returns the line of code in my view. Could someone help me to return the `@include` line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `view()->render();`

```
if($row->original_user_id == \Auth::id()){
     return view("partials.delete", ["id" => '.$advice->id.', "url" => URL::action("AdviceController@destroy")])->render();
}
```

Comment: This returns the error: `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\URL' not found`. Which class could I define for the use?

Comment: Lol. Simple `use URL;` did the trick! Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Yup hehe, glad it helps =]